# set date to 90 days from current unix timestamp

Tags: tcl

Hi i want to set my future_date variable to show a date that would be 90 days from today.

```
set $future_date ""
#set $future_date to date in unixtime stamp 90 days from the current timestamp
```

Can i do that in tcl?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Tcl, the `clock seconds` command returns the time now in term of seconds. To add 90 days to it, you have to multiply 90 by 60 (seconds in a minute), by 60 (minutes in an hour) and by 24 (hours in a day):

```
set today [clock seconds]
set future [expr {$today + 90 * 60 * 60 * 24}]
puts [clock format $today -format "Today is %B %m, %Y"]
puts [clock format $future -format "90 days from today is %B %m, %Y"]
```

Please look up the `clock` command for more information.

Comment: If only all days were exactly the same length! Unfortunately, they (subtly) aren't.

Comment: Agreed, Donal's is the preferred solution.

Comment: Date/time is a very complex topic. Thank you Donal and Glenn for pointing it out. Also, at work, we run Tcl 8.4, thus don't have access to the `clock add` command.

Answer (score 5):

The way to do it is to use `clock add`:

```
# The [clock seconds] produces _now_
set future_date [clock add [clock seconds] 90 days]
set future_readable [clock format $future_date]
```

OK, that's *almost* right. Firstly, it doesn't work for about half the year in some locales. The problem? They have DST changes that mean that the length of a day is actually not constant (sometimes, civil days are 23 or 25 hours long). However, applying such a correction requires knowledge of the current timezone (because different parts of the world have different rules). Timezones are specified with reference to the [zoneinfo database](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database):

```
set zone ":America/New_York"
set future_date [clock add [clock seconds] 90 days -timezone $zone]
set future_readable [clock format $future_date -timezone $zone]
# Normally should use the same timezone for each *unless* there's a
# business reason to do otherwise...
```

The second problem is that this ignores leap seconds. Mind you, if you're not writing GPS software or something else equally sensitive, this is probably exactly what you want (and if you *really do* care, you probably have suitable software/algorithms for applying the corrections anyway).

The third problem is that this only works from 8.5 onwards (when the `clock` command was rewritten virtually from scratch; we got tired of dealing with everyone else's bugs in time handling and decided to just have our own!) so if you're conservatively still using 8.4 (or before!) then you need a different incantation:

```
set future_date [clock scan "now + 90 days"]
set future_readable [clock format $future_date]
```

This isn't to be preferred, as it doesn't get timezone handling right (well, *might* use the current system timezone or might use UTC[*]) and is built on top of a highly non-obvious time string parser. Yet for all that, it's the best option pre-8.5.

---

[*] Do not underestimate how odd this can get; I remember dealing with a bug in a third party printer driver which, when loaded into a separate process on Windows, would change the system timezone for *all* running applications until the print run finished. Even confirming what was actually happening was hard (as was picking my jaw up off the floor afterward).